# dplyr-esque way to perform summary operations both grouped and ungrouped

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to be able to to perform the same operation on a set of data using `dplyr` multiple times. Each time I perform the operation, I want there to be a different set of columns on which I `group_by()`. How do I do this in the most dplyr-esque way (optimally, without copy and pasting the code or creating separate intermediate objects):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
    summarise(`Mean mpg` = mean(mpg),
              `Mean hp` = mean(hp))

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(`Mean mpg` = mean(mpg),
              `Mean hp` = mean(hp))
```

Just as some context, while this is a simple example, I'm more interested in extending its use to instances where I might be running a much longer pipeline of functions to, say, run a logistic regression model over stratified and unstratified data...but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking beyond what you've already coded.

Comment: As in...is there an elegant way to do this without just copy and pasting text. Again, this is a simple example.

Comment: What is "this"? What are you trying to abstract or generalize?

Comment: Performing the same operation on the same set of data, just grouped and ungrouped.

Comment: I think what you're getting is analogous to having a row belong two two groups at once, and then summarize across all groups. This has been discussed and is not (yet?) supported by `dplyr`, so the only current way to include a specific row in multiple groups is to do what you are doing: run the same `summarize` on different calls of `group_by`.

Comment: Do you have a list of variables you want to group by?

Comment: I kinda see where you're going with this...I could probably make one.

Comment: put it into a function that does that and takes the groups as a parameter? (read [this](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) where they do such a thing using NSE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If w don't know the number of groups, then one option is to use `...` (assuming that the variables to get the `mean` is the same

```
f1 <- function(dat, ...){
   dat %>%
      group_by_at(vars(...)) %>%
      summarise_at(vars('mpg', 'hp'), funs(Mean = mean(.)))
   }

f1(mtcars, 'cyl', 'gear')
#    cyl  gear mpg_Mean  hp_Mean
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     4     3   21.500  97.0000
#2     4     4   26.925  76.0000
#3     4     5   28.200 102.0000
#4     6     3   19.750 107.5000
#5     6     4   19.750 116.5000
#6     6     5   19.700 175.0000
#7     8     3   15.050 194.1667
#8     8     5   15.400 299.5000


f1(mtcars, 'cyl')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl mpg_Mean   hp_Mean
#   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     4 26.66364  82.63636
#2     6 19.74286 122.28571
#3     8 15.10000 209.21429
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I don't fully understand the different situations in which one would use each of the scoped variants of the dplyr functions, and this is the first time I've seen group_by_at in use.

Answer (score 0):

Again, while there may be many solutions the question posed above, I was looking for suggestions on a more elegant way to go about this/wondered if there was some method built into dplyr that I had failed to notice.

Another possible solution is as follows:

```
mtcars.2 <- mtcars %>% 
    mutate(gear = as.character(gear))

mtcars.2 <- bind_rows(mtcars.2,
                      mtcars.2 %>% 
                          mutate(gear = "All gears"))

mtcars.2 %>% 
    group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
    summarise(`Mean mpg` = mean(mpg),
              `Mean hp` = mean(hp))
```